# How add channel for wolframclient using conda?

Tags: python, conda

I want to use the wolframclient Python package in Mathematica. The docs suggest using `pip install wolframclient`.

However, my main Python installation is within conda, so I do *not* want to use `pip`, but instead a standard `conda install wolframclient`. (The problem with using `pip` is that the added package's dependencies may interfere with what conda has already installed and knows about.)

The `wolframclient` package is at https://pypi.org/project/wolframclient/. But by default conda does not know about pypi.org. I tried the command `conda config --add channels pipy`, but `conda install wolframclient` says the channel is "not accessible or is invalid".

I think the problem is that the files at `https://pypi.org/project/wolframclient/` are not already in the form of a conda package.

How might one proceed?

Answer (score 3):

> I think the problem is that the files at https://pypi.org/project/wolframclient/ are not already in the form of a conda package.

Yes, very precisely noted. Conda packages contain information about how to built in different format than pypi packages, which are made for `pip`.

In the case you describe, you ahve several options:

1. Create a seperate environment for `wolframclient` and use `pip install wolframclient` in there. Yes, `pip` and `conda` do not always get along, but by creating a virtual environment you have no risk of breaking other stuff and `pip` will be happy installing `wolframclient` for you
2. Check the `wolframclient` package on pypi and install the dependencies using `conda` before installing `wolframclient` with `pip` which might minimize the risk of having to many packages downloaded by `pip`
3. Download the [source code](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fe/69/17dc361d58b3ae335fcab8fe1b54d5018c9b4c78e133efca654c8a41e37e/wolframclient-1.1.2.tar.gz) of `wolframclient` and built it into a local conda package using `conda build` and [this guide](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs.html) and then use `conda install` to install the locally built package

Comment: Generally speaking option 1 should work fine as long as you first install everything you can get with `conda`, then install anything else with `pip`, and don't then try upgrading any packages in the environment - if you want to move to a later version of any package, just build a new environment by repeating the same process.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [conda build of wolframclient](https://anaconda.org/mgroth0/wolframclient) (current version: 1.1.4).